# Adding a namespace to the HTML element in Plone

Tags: plone

I'm looking to implement AddThis on a Plone site. In order for AddThis to track clicks, AddThis requires that the `fb` namespace needs to be declared on the `<html>` element:

https://www.addthis.com/help/third-party-buttons#facebook-like

The only way that I can think to do this is to override `main_template`, which I'm reluctant to do as it seems a rather extreme measure. At the moment I'm considering either putting the `fb` namespace on just the div containing the AddThis code, and crossing my fingers, or trying to roll my own solution which lacks this requirement.

As far as I can see, packages like [collective.addthis](http://plone.org/products/collective.addthis) don't bother with this.

Comment: You could place this in a viewlet by customizing maybe the plone.htmlhead.title viewlet in portal_view_customizations. That way you don't have to customize the main_template; however, you shouldn't fret too much about customizing the main_template either.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set this in DOM using JavaScript?  I am assuming you get a DOM that looks like what you want via:

```
 document.createAttributeNS('http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml', 'fb')
 document.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns:fb', 'http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml')
```

Comment: IMHO this is not a good option because doing so your page template won't be in well-formed xml

Comment: These methods are not well supported in IE according to SitePoint's reference. Also, I'm not sure this will cause the namespace to be added to the document's list---any further info?

Comment: I have no idea whether these will work across browsers, but the likelihood that this will work in standards mode in various browsers is at least worth a bit of testing.  This obviously is only potentially helpful if 'fb' namespaces elements are injected with JavaScript, not into templates server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Have you experimented with Diazo yet? Supplementing plone's html is straightforward. I've achieved exactly this in my diazo theme without the worry of overidding stuff

Comment: Unfortunately this is on an existing, traditionally themed site. But this is a great tip for future projects!